# export inside alias is not working in Bash

Tags: bash

I'm trying to do something like this. But it's not working.

```
$ alias setroot="export ROOT=$1; export PATH=$ROOT/bin:$PATH"
$ setroot /path/to/root
bash: export: `/path/to/root': not a valid identifier
```

Can someone point out, what is going wrong here?
To clarify, I need ROOT also in my environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alias is literally replaced and `$1` is empty, because your interactive shell was started with no arguments and all variables `$1`, `$ROOT` and `$PATH` are expanded *when defining your alias*, because you used double quotes. So:

```
setroot /path/to/root
```

does:

```
export ROOT=; export PATH=<content_of_ROOT>/bin:<content_of_PATH> /path/to/root
```

The second argument to second `export` is invalid identifier - `/path/to/root` contains `/`, and variables can't contain `/`. The `content_of_ROOT` is the value of `ROOT` *when defining alias*, not upon using it.

Use a function. Check your scripts with shellcheck.

Comment: But it works fine in case of `alias setroot="export ROOT=$1; cd $ROOT"`

Comment: In that case it does `alias setroot='export ROOT=; cd '` and `cd` just changed directory and it set's `ROOT` variable to empty. It does not work as you expect and `$1` does not have the value you expect it to have. Use ex. `( set -x ; setroot semething )` in command line debug your scripts. Research difference between single and double quotes.

Comment: Using a function just does the job and is probably the best option too. Thanks @KamilCuk

Comment: To my knowledge, I always thought Aliases could not receive Arguments. You have to work around that with a function.